# Multiple threading multiple lines of code in bash scripts

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Part of a script I have goes through all the IP addresses in the LAN, and checks the associated FQDN.

```bash
while [[ $ws -le $total_ip ]]; do
    ip="${ip_range}.${ws}"
    machine=$(timeout 0.3s python3 -c "import socket; print(socket.getfqdn('$ip'))")
    if[[ "$machine" = "$myMachine" ]]; then 
        my_ip=$ip
        break
    fi
done
```

This works right now, but takes quite a long time to complete.
I added a `timeout` command in front of the `python` command to make sure it doesn't go on for more than 0.3 seconds, but that still is quite long.

I want to know if I can thread this piece of code to speed up the process:

```
machine=$(timeout 0.3s python3 -c "import socket; print(socket.getfqdn('$ip'))")
if[[ "$machine" = "$myMachine" ]]; then 
    my_ip=$ip
    break
fi
```

However, it needs to be native bash, because I wan't to run this on other computers without having to install any additional tools.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question but you never increment `ws` so this seems like an infinite loop.

Comment: Also if you're already using python anyways it would probably be much faster to write the logic in a python script and not fork a couple hundred children.

Comment: Write it in python. `because I wan't to run this on other computers without having to install any additional tools.` You are literally using python.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post.
The thing with this script is that it needs to become all in one line eventually.
I'm not sure if I can do that in python.

Comment: What does 'all in one line' mean? `python3 -c '<commands>' "$myMachine" "$ip_range".{0..255}` is technically one line.

Comment: The shell has no support for threading. You can run multiple _processes_ but that's technically different; a process can have one or more threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) you can wrap your code into `{}` to group it. If a `&` is put behind this group, it will be executed asynchronously. to wait for all subprocesses to finish, use `wait`

Example:

```
{
    echo "foo"
    sleep 1
    echo "bar"
} &
echo "baz"
wait
```

Will output:

```
baz
foo
# and after one second
bar
```

more information on bash job control can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html).

Comment: This is true and accomplishes a degree of asynchronous behavior, but keep in mind that the backgrounded groups are run in subshells which limits how the parent shell can interact with them. For example `foo=bar ; { foo=baz ; } & wait ; echo "$foo"` prints `bar` because changes to variables in the subshell aren't reflected in the parent.

Comment: The impact for OP is that if they populate `my_ip` in one of these subshells they won't have access to it later - they'd have to find another way to tell the parent shell what IP they found, which adds some additional complexity to their eventual solution.

Comment: `echo $ip > /tmp/mymachine`

Answer (score 1):

A simple mostly-python solution. This passes the machine name and a range of IPs to check, prints the IP if found, and sets a non-zero exit code if it doesn't find an IP for the given machine name. The total runtime is just a few milliseconds if performance is your goal.

```
#!/bin/bash
myMachine=$1
ip_range=$2

if my_ip=$( python3 -c '
import sys
import socket
my_machine = sys.argv[1]
for ip in sys.argv[2:]:
  if socket.getfqdn(ip) == my_machine:
    print(ip)
    sys.exit(0)
sys.exit(1)
' "$myMachine" "$ip_range".{0..255} ) ; then
  echo "$myMachine IP: $my_ip"
else
  echo "IP for $myMachine not found."
fi
```

The timeout in your bash example does not improve performance much if at all because each individual instance of python is probably running very fast. Your performance issues are a result of spawning lots of child processes - `fork` is a very expensive system call, and you're forcing bash to call it repeatedly by invoking a new instance of `python3` on every iteration. Even adding "threading" would not improve performance much, because (again) the bottleneck is not that python is too slow, it's that creating an instance of python is a slow operation. Trying to solve the problem with multithreading is just going to result in very messy and error-prone code with minimal gains in performance.

The solution to this type of problem is normally to reduce the number of child processes you create, which is why I recommend calling `python3` only once and letting it do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thank you for proposing an answer to my question.
However the main issue was that it takes a long time to go through all 254 IP addresses, my bare for loops takes around 1.5 minutes to complete, while your proposed solution took around 5 minutes.

Comment: Also, I added the timeout because if the IP address is not up the python command will wait for about a second and then exit.
But if it is alive, then it doesn't take more than 0.3 seconds to return the FQDN